# Is there a way to visualize SyncTeX anchors in the PDF?

Tags: viewers, forward-inverse-search

Forward and reverse synchronization between the TeX source and the PDF output using SyncTeX is an immensely useful tool when writing larger documents. Sometimes, especially when the synchronization is not working as expected, I would like to see the synchronization anchors in the PDF file. I know that the information is stored in `.synctex.gz` file in some form, but this is hardly transparent for a human reader. Some graphical indication over the PDF output would be great. Does this exist?

I am working on Windows. Solutions for other systems are of course welcome, though they won't help me.

Comment: I'd say no: the generated PDF is the same with or without SyncTeX on.

Comment: If I get you right, context has a tracker to [visualize anchor points](https://texlive.net/run?%25%20!TeX%20context%0A%5Csetupexternalfigure%5Blocation=%7Bdefault%7D%5D%0A%5Csetupsynctex%5Bstate=start,method=min%5D%0A%5Cenabletrackers%5Bsystem.synctex.visualize%5D%0A%5Cstarttext%0A%5Csamplefile%7Bdouglas%7D%0A%5Cstartplacefloat%5Bfigure%5D%0A%5Cexternalfigure%5Bcow%5D%0A%5Cstopplacefloat%0A%5Csamplefile%7Btufte%7D%0A%5Cstoptext%0A). So it should probably be possible. (I don't use synctex, and have not really tested it...)

Comment: @mickep I don't think you do. I'm talking about SyncTeX anchors, which should be inaccessible from within TeX, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @egreg I was thinking more along the lines of the PDF viewer displaying those anchors on top of the PDF. All the TeX IDE viewers that support SyncTeX syncing with the source file have access to this information, after all.

Comment: And still you can see them in my example... Well well. ‍♂️

Comment: @mickep Does it? I can't tell. All I see is a bunch of underlined text. Creating a dummy document (with some explicit text) on my machine shows that a `.synctex.gz` file is created but synchronization between the `.tex` file and the `.pdf` file in my editor does not seem to work. The `synctex` command line utility also does not yield any synchronization information. So it seems like SyncTeX is not working with Context at all..? I don't know a lot about Context, so I may be missing something, but underlined text is not what I was looking for.

Comment: The underline is the tracking (that I thought you asked for). If the syncing does not work for you I cannot do much (I'm travelling, with phone only). Last time (admittedly a rather long time ago) I tried, it worked. But, my comment was merely to show that it is possible to show anchors, at least in context. In LaTeX I do not know... Sorry.